# Scala: Adding an element to Seq without breaking return type of method

Tags: scala

I have a method which returns Seq of certain type, say X. Its body is something like:

```
def myMethod = Seq(a,b)
```

where a and b are of type X.

Now I have to add another element to the sequence based on certain condition, something like this:

```
def myMethod = Seq(
  a,
  if(somecondition) c,
  b
)
```

But doing like this would change the type of Seq.
How can this be done without breaking things?

Comment: c is also of type X, and breaking things means client code is expecting Seq of type X only.

Comment: I actually need to add in middle of the list.

Comment: List size may vary in future, like adding another element based on some other condition. But order of elements is critical. Like above, c has to be added between a and b.

Comment: Why not use a `case class` modelled with `Option` type? is `Seq` a mandatory requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a lot of various conditions to apply in a similar way, one "trick" can be to use `Option`s like:

```scala
val s: Seq[Option[X]] = Seq(
  Some(a),
  if (someCondition) Some(c) else None,
  Some(b)
)
val s2: Seq[X] = s.flatten
```

This works because an `Option` is pretty much a `Seq` of one or 0 item.

If you only have one condition, I would go with Luis' solution: just put the `if` outside the sequence(s).

Comment: Another way can be...Seq(Seq(a) ++ if(condition) Seq(c) else Seq.Empty ++ Seq(b)).flatten...

Comment: @Mandroid then the outer **Seq** is not necessary. Also, this one is way more inefficient.